# How to find the median?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, median

I am trying to create a function that can get any number of inputs and find the median. I feel like I am going about this all wrong, I cannot get this functional.
What do I need to do?

1. I made my list
2. I asked user for inputs
3. I sorted with numpy
4. I printed median

Code:

```
import numpy

numbers = [1,2,3]                
1 = input("Please type your first number")            
2 = input("please type your second number")       
3 = input("please type your third number")       
median = numpy.median(numbers)            
print(median)
```

What I am trying to accomplish:

What numbers would you like to find the median for? 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
The median is: 4

Comment: You can't assign to `1`. `1` is a number; you can't turn it into `2` or something.

Comment: I am just starting out programming,I did not know that. How would I assign it?

Comment: Assign to variables or list elements, or append the input to a list.

Comment: Did you install NumPy?

Comment: Just DL it! Its working now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should store the numbers in a list, and use a loop to add numbers to it.

```
import numpy

size = int(input("Enter number of numbers you would like to enter"))
numbers = []
for i in range(size):
    numbers.append(int(input("Please type in number %d" % i)))

median = numpy.median(numbers)  

print(median)
```

Your approach fails because you try to use numbers as variable names, which is not valid.

Comment: Not sure what is wrong with this answer, so I would like some feedback!

Comment: Being a novice programmer, I was unaware that I would have to download NumPY, after doing so I ended up using this. This was helpful!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign values to 1, 2, or 3. Additionally, you need to convert the strings from `input` to `int`s. Try some simple changes.

```
import numpy                
input1 = input("Please type your first number")            
input2 = input("Please type your second number")       
input3 = input("Please type your third number")
numbers = map(int, [input1, input2, input3])
median = numpy.median(numbers)            
print(median)
```

Comment: I see my code was misleading, this helps me see what I should have done for functionality. Although I was going for what @jh314 posted.